# what happens when a service is started multiple times

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have created a simple service which will increment a counter and log it.

```
    public class AudioService extends Service {
    int i=0;
    private final IAudioInterface.Stub mBinder = new IAudioInterface.Stub() {

            public int getI()
            {
                return i;
            }

        };

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

            Log.d("onBind from service","****");

            return mBinder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {

            super.onCreate();
            Log.d("onCreate from service","***");
            Log.d("i=","="+i);
            i=i+1;


        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.d("OnDestroy Called from service","***");


        }

        public void onStartCommand(Intent intent, int startId) {
            super.onStart(intent, startId); 
            Log.d("onStartCommand from service","***");

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
            Log.d("onUnbind from service","***");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
        }
```

i am incrementing the i value in the oncreate method of he service.

The Client Activity is as shown below

```
 public class AidlInterfaceServiceActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private static final String TAG = "Audio:Service";
IAudioInterface mService = null;
boolean connected = false;
ServiceConnection mConnection  = new ServiceConnection(){

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder service) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        connected = true;
        Log.d("Service connected","**");
        mService = IAudioInterface.Stub.asInterface(service);

        try {
            Log.d("i from client","="+mService.getI());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "Service disConnected");
        connected = false;
        mService= null;
    }
 };


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.d("on created ","**********");

    Intent music = new Intent();
    music.setClass(this,AudioService.class);
    startService(music);
    bindService(music, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


}
```

The AIDL file is as below

```
interface IAudioInterface
{

    int getI();
}
```

The problem is when i run the client activity every time the value of i is "0".
i value is not getting incremented.

I have these queries.
1.what happens when the service is started multiple time.
2.what happens when the service is bounded multiple times.
3.what happens to the data members inside the service class when it is started multiple times.Does those data members get reinitialized.

I am really confused ..Any one please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it help if you declare your counter variable as static?